# Issue with XML UTF-8/ISO-8859-1 encoding with Chinese characters on Linux

Tags: xml, linux, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a XML file (response.xml) on Linux that I am trying to parse using awk/sed/grep, etc. The XML file contains some Chinese characters, and I am trying to get the value of the FunCode

```
<FunCode>9000</FunCode>
```

1. Using `view` or `cat` on Linux:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
           <ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement xmlns:ns31="http://www.example.com/schema/xyzWS">
               <ns31:UploadInboundResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encodi®æå&lt;/Remark>&lt;/Head>&lt;/ATKCST>>unCode>9000&lt;/FunCode>&lt;Remark>æ¥æ¶æ°æ
               </ns31:UploadInboundResult>
           </ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement>
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```
2. Using the `file` command on Linux:

   ```
   $ file -b --mime-encoding response.xml
   $ utf-8
   ```
3. On Windows using Notepad, the file looks like this. Notice that the encoding is UTF-8:

   ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
           <ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement xmlns:ns31="http://www.example.com/schema/xyzWS">
               <ns31:UploadInboundResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>&lt;ATKCST>&lt;Head>&lt;FunCode>9000&lt;/FunCode>&lt;Remark>接收数据成功&lt;/Remark>&lt;/Head>&lt;/ATKCST></ns31:UploadInboundResult>
           </ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement>
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```
4. Yet, when I open the file using any web browser on Windows, it shows this. Notice that the encoding is ISO-8859-1:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Body>
           <ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement xmlns:ns31="http://www.example.com/schema/xyzWS">
               <ns31:UploadInboundResult>
                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                   <ATKCST>
                       <Head>
                           <FunCode>9000</FunCode>
                           <Remark>接收数据成功</Remark>
                       </Head>
                   </ATKCST>
               </ns31:UploadInboundResult>
           </ns31:UploadInboundResponseElement>
       </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
   ```

So the file is formatted correctly in the browser, but I am confused why Linux says that the file is UTF-8 encoded, while inside the browser it shows up as ISO-8859-1.

Is it simply because of the "encoding='UTF-8'"?

My other (main) question is that on Linux, I am unable to search and grab the value "9000" for the FunCode.

Any ideas on how I can format the file on Linux so that I can get the value of the FunCode? I tried using "iconv", but that did not help.

Comment: not recommended, highly brittle, likely to fail when `sed` sees the Chinese chars, will not work if this is split across one or more lines (which is legal XML), ... you should be using `xmlstarlet`, but .... here you go `echo "<FunCode>9000</FunCode>" | sed -n 's@<FunCode>@@;s@</FunCode>@@p'` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter This is not a typical XML value extraction question, it's about the weird encoding

Comment: It looks like your Linux terminal just doesn't support UTF-8 and garbles the output. Notepad appears to be showing the double-encoded XML value correctly. Can you post the file base64 encoded or hex dumped so that it's possible to examine the actual data more closely?

Comment: I agree there seems to be a lot of extra information here, but the O.P. did write at the top of the Q -- *I am trying to get the value of the FunCode*, hence my comment. Just sayin! ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: "I am trying to parse using awk/sed/grep," - these tools do not understand XML syntax which basically means you have to do the parsing yourself. There are many problems with that, well documented in other SO answers, but the particular problem here is probably that these tools (not being XML-aware) won't  follow the correct XML rules for detecting the file encoding. Use a real XML parser.

Comment: @that other guy - yes the weird encoding is what is causing an issue for me on Linux. If the <FunCode> has appeared as normal text, I could simply use the following to get the value: funcode=$(sed -ne '/FunCode/{s/.*<FunCode>\(.*\)<\/FunCode>.*/\1/p;q;}' response.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mess you're seeing in Linux is most likely due to a misconfigured terminal. Given the contents you see in Notepad, you would have to decode the UploadInboundResult as text, reinterpret it as XML, and then finally get your element:

```
  $ xmlstarlet sel -T -N ns='http://www.example.com/schema/xyzWS' \
         -t -v '//ns:UploadInboundResult' response.xml |
      xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//FunCode' -n
  9000
```

Comment: I tried xmllint with various options, but none of them worked. Unfortunately, I don't have xmlstarlet installed on RHEL :-(. Looks like this is the only option